# Mac OS X: Is there a way to jump to a folder containing a file found in command-space

Tags: macos, mac, folder-redirection

I have a file that I can open using spotlight search

But I don't have a single idea where it is located on the system and grep filename, hasn't found it after more than 15 minutes of searching. I was wondering if there is some work around that allows me to jump to the folder containing a file found in spotlight search.

I noticed that command-click, ctrl-click don't do anything interesting in spotlight search.

Comment: Try `locate $filename` in Terminal  (with appropriate substitution for $filename, of course).

Comment: I do know the filename not the folder name

Comment: `locate $filename` should return the full path to the file; although Tetsujin has given a more mac-appropriate answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  + double-click will open the enclosing folder, with your file selected.

Comment: Most welcome :) please feel free to mark this as the Accepted answer, to help future Googlers.